# yum.repos.d and dnf repolist don't seem to agree on how many repos are installed

Tags: dnf, alma-linux

The list of (installed?) repos in
/etc/yum.repos.d [ count: 16 ]

is way way different from the list of installed repos I get from
dnf repolist --all [ count: 42 ]

Comment: I'm not surprised to see the two values differ, but is there any chance your second value is a typo? A single file in `/etc/yum.repos.d` can define multiple files, so in a stock almalinux-8 container, I see 9 files in `/etc/yum.repos.d`, but 33 repositories in `dnf repolist --all`.

Comment: There was a typo, the counts for each were transposed. Fixing it now.

Dropping this here to be sure I get 'em right this time

$ ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d | wc -l
16
$ dnf repolist --all | wc -l
42

Comment: So it seems likely that you simply have multiple repositories listed per file.

Comment: I see what you mean @larsks ... 
eg. yum.repos.d/epel.repos sets up 4 repos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files in /etc/yum.repos.d can each address enable and disable multiple repos
They are 1 -> n

dnf repolist --all
lists all "n"